# Parameter allocation for MPI collectives

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

This is my first python MPI program, and I would really appreciate some help optimizing the code.  Specifically, I have two questions regarding scattering and gathering, if anyone can help.  This program is much slower than a traditional approach without MPI.

I am trying to scatter one array, do some work on the nodes which fills another set of arrays, and gather those.  My questions are primarily in the setup and gather sections of code.

- Is it necessary to allocate memory for an array on all nodes? (`A`, `my_A`, `xset`, `yset`, `my_xset`, `my_yset`)?  Some of these can get large.
- Is an array the best structure to gather for the data I am using?  When I scatter A, it is relatively small.  However, `xset` and `yset` can get very large (over a million elements at least).

Here is the code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

#Libraries
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
print "%d nodes running."% (comm.size)

#Variables
cmin = 0.0
cmax = 4.0
cstep = 0.005
run = 300
disc = 100

#Setup
if comm.rank == 0:
    A = py.arange(cmin, cmax + cstep, cstep)
else:
    A = py.arange((cmax - cmin) / cstep, dtype=py.float64)

my_A = py.empty(len(A) / comm.size, dtype=py.float64)
xset = py.empty(len(A) * (run - disc) * comm.size, dtype=py.float64)
yset = py.empty(len(A) * (run - disc) * comm.size, dtype=py.float64)
my_xset = py.empty(0, dtype=py.float64)
my_yset = py.empty(0, dtype=py.float64)

#Scatter
comm.Scatter( [A, MPI.DOUBLE], [my_A, MPI.DOUBLE] )

#Work
for i in my_A:
    x = 0.5
    for j in range(0, run):
        x = i * x * (1 - x)
        if j >= disc:
            my_xset = py.append(my_xset, i)
            my_yset = py.append(my_yset, x)

#Gather
comm.Allgather( [my_xset, MPI.DOUBLE], [xset, MPI.DOUBLE])
comm.Allgather( [my_yset, MPI.DOUBLE], [yset, MPI.DOUBLE])

#Export Results
if comm.rank == 0:
    f = open('points.3d', 'w+')
    for k in range(0, len(xset)-1):
        f.write('(' + str(round(xset[k],2)) + ',' + str(round(yset[k],2)) + ',0)\n')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

- You do not need to allocate `A` on the non-root processes. If you were not using `Allgather`, but a simple `Gather`, you could also omit `xset` and `yset`. Basically you only need to allocate data that is actually used by the collectives - the other parameters are *only significant on root*.
- Yes, a numpy array is an appropriate data structure for such large arrays. For small data where it is not performance-critical, it can be more convenient and pythonic to use the all-lowercase methods and communicate with Python objects (lists etc).